# How to mock PythonOperator's python_callable and on_failure_callback?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, airflow

What and where do I mock, with an Airflow `PythonOperator`,  such that:

- the `python_callback` raises a exception, triggering the call of the `on_failure_callback`, and
- I can test whether that callback is called, and with what arguments?

I have tried mocking both the {python_callable} and `PythonOperator.execute`, in a number of places, without success.

The code files look something like this:

**dags/my_code.py**

```
class CustomException(Exception): pass

def a_callable():
    if OurSqlAlchemyTable.count() == 0:
        raise CustomException("{} is empty".format(OurSqlAlchemyTable.name))
    return True

def a_failure_callable(context):
    SlackWebhookHook(
        http_conn_id=slack_conn_id,
        message= context['exception'].msg,
        channel='#alert-channel'
        ).execute()
```

**dags/a_dag.py**

```
from my_code import a_callable, a_failure_callable

new_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='new-task', dag=dag-named-sue, conn_id='a_conn_id', timeout=30,
    python_callable=a_callable,
    on_failure_callback=a_failure_callable)
```

**dags/test_a_dag.py**

```
class TestCallback(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_on_failure_callback(self):
        tested_task = DagBag().get_dag('dag-named-sue').get_task('new-task')

        with patch('airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonOperator.execute') as mock_execute:
            with patch('dags.a_dag.a_failure_callable') as mock_callback:
                mock_execute.side_effect = CustomException
                tested_task.execute(context={})

            # does failure of the python_callable trigger the failure callback?
        mock_callback.assert_called()

            # did the exception message make it to the failure callback?
        failure_context = mock_callback.call_args[0]
        self.assertEqual(failure_context['exception'].msg,
                        'OurSqlAlchemyTable is empty')O
```

The test does raise `CustomException` at the line `self.task.execute(context={})` -- but, in the test code itself.  What I want is for that error to be
raised in the Airflow code such that the `PythonOperator` fails and calls `on_failure_callback`.

I have tried any number of permutations, all either raising in test without
triggering, calling the python_callable, or not finding an object to patch:

```
patch('dags.a_dag.a_callable') as mock_callable
      'a_dag.a_callable'
      'dags.my_code.a_callable'
      'my_code.a_callable'
      'airflow.models.Task.execute'
```

(`Python3`, `pytest`, and `mock`.)

**What am I missing / doing wrong?**

(Better still, I would like to verify the arguments passed to `SlackWebhookHook`.  Something like:

```
with patch('???.SlackWebhookHook.execute') as mock_webhook:
    ... as above ...

kw_dict = mock_webhook.call_args[-1]
assert kw_dict['http_conn_id'] == slack_conn_id
assert kw_dict['message'] == 'OurSqlAlchemyTable is empty'
assert kw_dict['channel'] == '#alert-channel'
```

(But I am first focussing on testing the failure callback.)

Thank you in advance.